# What this code means when I duplicate a rendering

Tags: sxa

Can someone please explain me on some example, what these lines of code means. I duplicated the rendering and now I see this code, and I am so confused by it.
[image]

What is the meaning of `Html.Sxa().BeginEditFrame`, and what these parameters means in general, it does not have to be precise `slide.Id.ToString()` and etc.

[image]

This `Model.Attributes` what is the meaning of it?

Comment: This means that if you add this component on the page and open it in Experience Editor then it will show a frame around the image and you will find options on Experience Editor to update the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is for Using EditFrames in the SXA component. EditFrames in the Experience Editor is a feature that you can use to give users front-end access to fields that are not directly accessible, either because they are not visible or they are of a type that are not directly front-end editable.

In above code code, `slide.Id.ToString()` is your Item's ID on which you want to edit the fields, `"Image"` is the `EditFreame` button name which you can find in core database under WebEdit section-
`Applications > WebEdit >` and `Model.Attribute` is checking is component is editable or not.

See this article for reference - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/editing-your-sitecore-experience-accelerator-sxa-list-jen-pearson/